# Laravel Implicit model binding naming convention?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using implicit model binding on my controller actions, but I have have a model called `VerifiedDocument` and no matter what I put in as the model name I cannot seem to get it to load into my action, but if I do:

```
    Route::bind('verificationDocument', function ($value) {
        return VerificationDocument::where('id', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
    });
```

it works.

What naming convention does Laravel use for implicit model binding?

Comment: This is actually explicit https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: What does your route definition and controller method look like? The parameter name in the route has to match the variable name in the controller and you have to type hint the model. If one or both of those isn't set up properly the implicit binding won't work.

Comment: Also instead of using the abort function there you can use `->firstOrFail()`

Comment: Depending on the version of Laravel because of PHP version support, you might be specifying the namespace wrong. For instance <= v5.2 used a string like so: `'App\User'`, and > v5.2 used the class feature like so: `App\User::class`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIRC the naming convention for implicit binding is between the parameter name and the type-hinted variable name, i.e:

```
// Route declaration
Route::get('verificationdocuments/{verification_document}', YourController@show);

// Controller Action
public function show(VerificationDocument $verification_document)

// or without controller
Route::get('documents/{document}', function (VerificationDocument $document) {
    return $document->title;
});
```

Note that `{verification_document} => $verification_document` and `{document} => $document`